# User_likes not shown SDK Facebook for PHP 3.2.3

Tags: php, facebook

I try to get my user_likes. I got an access token in the Graph API Explorer for user_likes. When I put hardly my **PAGE_ID_WANT_TO_CHECK** and my **ACCESS_TOKEN_USER_LIKES** in the url bar, my datas are good shown in my browser. But, in my code when I make the test if my $likes are empty or not, it still say it's empty.

`var_dump($likes)` is just empty.

Would like to know why and how to have a full array ?

Here my code.

Thank you.

```
require_once('fb-sdk/facebook.php');
require_once('config.php');

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  if ($user_id) {

    try {
      $likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes/PAGE_ID_WANT_TO_CHECK?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_USER_LIKES');
        if( !empty($likes['data']) ){
            echo "I LIKE!!!!!!";
        }else{
          echo "not a fan!";
        }
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
      }

    }

var_dump($likes['data']);


//During the login process
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
  ));
```

Comment: facebook.php includes base_facebook.php already...

Comment: also, the whole point of using a facebook sdk (amongst other things) is that you do not need to worry about the access token at all. it getUser works, there is no need to add the access token on your own. just make sure you request user_likes in the login process and it shows up in the dialog.

Comment: Be aware that asking users that do not have a role in the app (i.e., the “general public”) for `user_likes` permission requires approval by Facebook from API v2 on – and you will not get it granted for the simple purpose of checking if the user liked a specific page. “Like gating” is not allowed any more.